# Taking advantage of Kaggle's free GPUs and TPUs

Tags: python, kaggle

How do you run your Python code on Kaggle without organizing it into a single notebook or script?
Here's what I'm trying to achieve: I have several Python scripts containing class definitions as well as the application logic, and I would like to run them as-is on Kaggle and take advantage of their freely-available GPUs and TPUs.

I'd rather not turn everything into a single .ipynb or .py file as it would get pretty messy due to the several import statements in each script (which would need to be fixed), although it seems to be the only way to do that. Are there any alternatives to run my code on Kaggle while taking advantage of GPUs/TPUs? If not, are there any other platforms that offer "free" GPUs?

Comment: From the file menu in the editor click on "Add utility script". More details here: https://www.kaggle.com/product-feedback/91185

Comment: While this works, I find it a little bit tedious to load and save one script at a time. Nonetheless, I guess this solution is as good as it gets, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You can import the files into each other. That way, you can run it all on one separate file that imports all the files. If you can only run one file, I'd advise you run them all on one file, or perhaps look into threading to run them all at once through one file.

Comment: Actually, my scripts already contain the necessary import statements. However, the problem with Kaggle is that not only are you allowed to run only one file, but you also cannot upload more than one file on the platform. This means that your're forced to copy-paste the code contained in each of your Python scripts into a single file, which is obviously horrible.